# Accessing Named Attribute in a Matrix

Tags: r, scale

I am wondering about the output when applying the scale() function to a data frame, you get a matrix. When looking at the attributes of the output, I see that there is are two elements

```
attr(,"scaled:center")
col1 mean col2 mean etc
attr(,"scaled:scale")
col1 sd col2 sd etc
```

How exactly do these two attributes fit into the matrix that is given by scale(). First, it is not clear how there is a named attribute with a numeric vector, I haven't been able to find anything on assigning a numeric vector as an attribute. Second, how are these values accessed? Say I want to reverse the scale function applied to matrix A, something like

```
(A * A$scaled:scale) + A$scaled:center
```

Does not work. I am really lost as to what is going on here and would really appreciate any advice or guidance on what these vectors are (just two extra rows tacked on to the initial matrix?) and how one might access their values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the attributes like this:

```
m <- matrix(1:25,5,5)
ms <- scale(m)
# See all attributes
> attributes(ms)
$dim
[1] 5 5

$`scaled:center`
[1]  3  8 13 18 23

$`scaled:scale`
[1] 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139

> attr(x = ms,"dim")
[1] 5 5
> attr(x = ms,which = "scaled:center")
[1]  3  8 13 18 23
```

And you can add new attributes like this:

```
attr(ms,"foo") <- 1:10
> attributes(ms)
$dim
[1] 5 5

$`scaled:center`
[1]  3  8 13 18 23

$`scaled:scale`
[1] 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139

$foo
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

As @joran pointed out, teh attrributes are not actually named items in the matrix, but rather need to be access with `attr()`. The following will let you recover the original (to within numeric precision limits:

```
 apply( sweep(ms, 2, attr(ms,"scaled:scale"), '*') ,
           2,   # Need to add back column-by-column
           '+', attr(ms,"scaled:center")) 

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    7    7    7    7    7
[3,]   13   13   13   13   13
[4,]   19   19   19   19   19
[5,]   25   25   25   25   25
```

You are first reversing the scaling of the centered values and then "uncentering" that result. Needs to be done in reversed order of the original algorithm which you can see with `scale.default`.

Another way would be with "nested" calls to `sweep`. My first effort mislead me regarding the need to substitute apply for sweep:

```
> sweep( sweep(ms, 2, attr(ms,"scaled:scale"), '*') ,
         2, attr(ms,"scaled:center"),'+') 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1]  3  8 13 18 23
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139 1.581139
```

It would probably be better to NULL out those attributes, since they were untouched by the "unsweep" operation.